# Css transition not entirely working

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Hey im looking to get a smooth transition for my mobile first website but the body keeps jumping to the position instead of transitioning.
The site is http://868rcacs.ca/_new/

My JQuery

```
(function(){
    var body = $('body');
    $('.menu-button').bind('click', function(){
        body.toggleClass('menu-open');
        return false;
    });
})();
```

Css

```
.menu{
position: fixed;
left: -250px;
width: 250px;
height: 100%;
background: #333;
color: #fff;
top: 0;
padding-top: 5px;
}
.body{
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
left: 0px;
}
.menu-open .menu{
left: 0px;
z-index: 20;
}
.menu-open .menu-button {
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
}
.menu-open .wrapper{
left: 0px;
}
.menu-open .overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.menu-open, .menu{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.login-bar {
padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Anyone know why the nav is properly moving while the body/.wrapper is not?

Comment: You have a footer after your body and no closing html tag by the way. So first things first, fix that.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with semi-stripped down version of your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/RBjHt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply transition to your wrapper as well

```
.wrapper {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong, but in the first case, try declaring body without a dot in your css :

```
.body{}
```

should be

```
body{}
```

Comment: The OP gave his body a class of body.